# Will the LPUSH command work on a record that was initialized from JSON?

Tags: redis

If a redis record was set from a JSON object that contains a list in it, could the LPUSH command be later used on that list to update it? (using redis on node.js)
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.
Redis is format agnostic.
It cannot parse JSON, and it is not a document oriented database.

LPUSH applies to Redis list objects only.

What can be done however using Lua Redis 2.6 server-side scripting capability, is a script to decode a JSON object, add the item, encode back the object and store it.

For instance, with the following JSON object:

```
set users:1 "{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Rocco\",\"age\":50,girlfriends:[\"Ulla\"]}"
```

adding a new girlfriend can be implemented in one operation using an [eval command](http://redis.io/commands/eval):

```
eval "local t = cjson.decode( redis.call('get',KEYS[1] ))
  if t.girlfriends then
     table.insert(t.girlfriends,ARGV[1])
  else
     t.girlfriends = {ARGV[1]}
  end
  return redis.call('set',KEYS[1], cjson.encode(t))
" 1 user:1 Augusta
```

Another possibility is to avoid storing JSON objects directly in Redis, but write a layer to convert JSON objects into several Redis keys (isolating the lists sections in their specific keys).

For instance:

```
 { "id":1, "name": "Rocco", "age":50,
  girlfriends: [ "Ulla", "Bella", "Josepha", "Isabella" ] }
```

could be stored as:

```
 HMSET users:1:info name Rocco age 50
 RPUSH users:1:girlfriends Ulla Bella Josepha Isabella
```

The main benefits of this approach are performance and partial update support. Main drawback is some flexibility is lost and conversion code may be tedious to write.